# Gogs and Gitea feature query

Tags: git, gogs, gitea

Could you please let me know what all below features are available in gogs and gitea ?

```
Local Repo Administration
Support for Microsoft Active Directory
User Roles
Merge Request Reviewer
Protect direct push on master
Leaving comments on Merge Request
Merge Request Diffs
Cherry pick changes from UI
Revert Changes/patch/pull request/merger request From UI
Integration with other build server like jenkins and teamcity
Support for Private Repositories
Notifications-Issue/Merge request events
Backup and DR
```

Answer (score 0):

Now you can see all features in the [`gitea` comparison table](https://docs.gitea.io/en-us/comparison/)